# How to convert data stored in a text file to csv

Tags: python, csv, text, text-files

I periodically upload data in the form of a text file that is structured similar to this:

```
>up
upload 06/14/2021 24:58:09.99 255
————- upload start ————-
2021–06–14 24:58:09.99 upload complete
2021–06–14 24:58:44.05 parameter change: mux sequence '1234'
2021–06–14 24:58:46.88 R 0000_0000000114023569 A1 168
2021–06–14 24:58:49.30 R 0000_0000000114023569 A2 168
————- upload done ————-
```

In this example, the actual data starts on the sixth line, where if the data had headers, it would look like this:

```
DetectDate  DetectTime DetectType    ID                 Location     sublocation
2021–06–14 24:58:46.88    R       0000_0000000114023569 A1            168
```

Note that the data doesn't always start on the sixth line. I need to re-organize this data and store it in a .csv with the headers mentioned above. I would also like to add columns for UploadDate and UploadTime, and collect that information from the text file. So the final .csv would have the following columns:

```
DetectDate  DetectTime DetectType ID Location  sublocation UploadDate UploadTime
```

How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you know data always start on the sixth line and stop just before the last you can use Pandas to do that easily using:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

inputStr = """>up
upload 06/14/2021 24:58:09.99 255
————- upload start ————-
2021–06–14 24:58:09.99 upload complete
2021–06–14 24:58:44.05 parameter change: mux sequence '1234'
2021–06–14 24:58:46.88 R 0000_0000000114023569 A1 168
2021–06–14 24:58:49.30 R 0000_0000000114023569 A2 168
————- upload done ————-"""

filteredInput = '\n'.join(inputStr.splitlines()[5:-1])
coNames = ['DetectDate', 'DetectTime', 'DetectType', 'ID', 'Location', 'sublocation']
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(filteredInput), delimiter=r'\s+', header=None, names=coNames)
print(f)
```

Which gives:

```
   DetectDate   DetectTime DetectType                     ID Location  sublocation
0  2021–06–14  24:58:46.88          R  0000_0000000114023569       A1          168
1  2021–06–14  24:58:49.30          R  0000_0000000114023569       A2          168
```

To store `df` in a file, you can use `df.to_csv(filePath)`.

If you need a more advanced parsing, you can play with regular expressions (using the `re` Python module).